# a relationship between local compactness and closure

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a Hausdorff locally compact space and $S$ a subset of $X$. Let $x\in X$ and suppose that every compact neighborhood of $x$ intersects $S$. Does it follow that $x$ lies in the closure of $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Since $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, given a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$, we can find a neighborhood $V$ such that $\overline V$ is compact and $\overline V\subseteq U$. As every compact neighborhood of $x$ intersects with $S$, $\overline V\cap S\neq \emptyset$ $\implies U\cap S\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Yes I was doubting if every neighborhood has a compact neighborhood so I need to prove this fact now

Comment: You can find a proof in 'Topology' by Munkres.

Comment: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520538/equivalent-definition-of-locally-compact-when-x-is-hausdorff-how-did-they-get).

Comment: Thanks I’m looking them up

Answer (score 1):

In this case ($X$ being locally compact Hausdorff) for every point $x$ of $X$, every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a compact neighbourhood of $x$ - [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space).

Then any neighbourhood of $x$ contains a compact neighbourhood which intersects $S$, so $x\in \bar{S}$